# Telegram client for android: how to get last message?

Tags: java, android, telegram

I want to built a custom Telegram client for android with a function to save messages into file. As a base project, I'm using official source code: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram
And I can't find a way to actually get a message. In Documentation for Telegram mentioned method getChatHistory https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1get_chat_history.html
But I don't see any usage of the API in their code. Instead, they are used custom classes somehow similar to API. And the general class for any actions with messages is MessageObject. I can get the text content of this object by using this

```
message.messageText.toString();
```

where message is object of class MessageObject, but how I can create this object?
The supposed workflow is: when interested chat is opened, besides already existed common buttons, custom button for save message is appearing, after tapping this button, begins a cycle in which we create object of class MessageObject start with id of last message in chat, we extrating a text from this message, and saves it a file.